# Como Esconder el teclado virtual en un Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Hola he visto otros post sobre esto, pero ninguno solucionan este problema.

En realidad el teclado se oculta, pero no como debe de ocultarse, porque se sigue mostrando como el fondo del teclado.

Eso mismo también pasa cuando pulso en unos botones que tengo para guardar el documento, borrarlo, etc.. el teclado desaparece, *pero se queda ese fondo*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ocultar el teclado tengo puesto este código en una actividad que extiende de un **Fragment**:

```
 binding.btApuntesGuardar3.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        .....
        .....
        .....
         CerrarTeclado();
 });


 private void CerrarTeclado() {
     View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
     if (view != null) {
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
         view.clearFocus();
     }
 }
```

**archivo.xml**

```
     <LinearLayout>
 
         <ScrollView>
 
             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:orientation="vertical">
 
                 <TextView />
 
                 <LinearLayout
                      android:orientation="horizontal">
                     <ImageButton/>
                     <EditText/>
                     <ImageButton />
                     <ImageButton />
                 </LinearLayout>
 
                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/txt_apunte_contenido_3"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                     android:background="#1634F7"
                     android:ems="10"
                     android:gravity="top"
                     android:imeOptions="actionNone|actionUnspecified|flagNoFullscreen|flagNoExtractUi"
                     android:importantForAutofill="no"
                     android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                     android:minLines="7"
                     android:scrollbars="vertical"
                     android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
 
             </LinearLayout>
 
         </ScrollView>
 
     </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
```

En el siguiente gif se puede ver que, al escribir en el EditText, el teclado se muestra, pero al intentar ocultarlo desde la flecha física del móvil, paso lo siguiente:

Que puedo hacer para que se oculte el teclado y no se quede esa especie de fondo que contenía el teclado?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo que falla es el método CerrarTeclado(), esta validando la vista si esta tiene el enfoque, pero en este caso puede ser que no obtenga la vista por esta razón no esconde el teclado, te sugiero cambiar el método :

```
private void cerrarTeclado() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
            view = (view == null) ? new View(getActivity()) : view;
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, lo he cambiado por tu código, y he tenido que quitar **public static void** y dejarlo como **public void** porque me muestra un error en `getActivity()` y aun así, el problema sigue, y que curioso, antes no me di cuenta, pero si pulso en otras pestañas/tabs del menú, se sigue mostrando es fondo, en todos las pestañas de menú.

Comment: Ok entonces en la misma activity estas reemplazando varios Fragment?

Comment: Tengo creado un menú con `ViewPager2`, en total 12 pestañas, por cierto va lentísimo con `setOffscreenPageLimit()`, y cada pestaña tiene un Frangment con diferente contenido, solo en primera pestaña tengo puesto un botón para abrir otro fragment que es el que contiene el `EditText`, no se si es esto lo que preguntas.

Comment: bueno Jorgesys, ya puede solucionar este problema con el siguiente código:
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(introLogin.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

Pero.... hay otro pequeño problema, que voy a plantearlo en otro post, porque no se si tiene que con este, gracias.